# HTML5 Audio tag not working with IIS7 in different environments

Tags: c#, android, ios, html, audio

I have implemented an HTML5 audio player on a webpage that uses standard ashx handlers to serve the .mp3 to the player. When testing this new feature locally, it works great in all browsers on the desktop as well as android and iOS. Once deploying the project to the test server I loose functionality only in android (the file will not play at all, this isn't an autoplay issue or anything). Once deploying code to the production environment android works again but I loose iOS.

Based on what I have looked at so far it seems to be an issue in IIS. When I localize the file to the web server instead of serving from the db I run into the same issue.

The MIME types are all set up correctly and are the same across the environments, Handler Mappings match in all environments, HTTP Response Headers are the same across the environments.

I'm not sure what other settings in IIS could cause this issue.